# Create a new column based on other columns as indices for another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's suppose I have one dataframe with at least two columns col1 and col2. Also I have another dataframe whose column names are values in col 1 and whose indices are values in col2.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'col1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x2'], 'col2': ['y0', 'y1', 'y0']})
print(df1)
  col1 col2
0   x1   y0
1   x2   y1
2   x2   y0

print(df2)
     y0   y1
x1    1    4
x2    2    5
x3    3    6
```

Now I wish to add col3 that gives me the value of the second dataframe at index of col1 and in column of col2.
The result should look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    x1    y0     1
1    x2    y1     5
2    x2    y0     2
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for new `df` with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
print (df2)
  col1 col2  col3
0   x1   y0     1
1   x1   y1     4
2   x2   y0     2
3   x2   y1     5
4   x3   y0     3
5   x3   y1     6

print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col1','col2'], how='left'))
  col1 col2  col3
0   x1   y0     1
1   x2   y1     5
2   x2   y0     2
```

Another solution is create new `Series` with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df2.stack().rename('col3')
print (s)
  col1 col2
0   x1   y0
1   x2   y1
2   x2   y0
x1  y0    1
    y1    4
x2  y0    2
    y1    5
x3  y0    3
    y1    6
Name: col3, dtype: int64

print (df1.join(s, on=['col1','col2']))
  col1 col2  col3
0   x1   y0     1
1   x2   y1     5
2   x2   y0     2
```

Comment: second one's classy.

Comment: @NickilMaveli - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple join

Pandas supports the join operation both on indexes and on columns, meaning you can do this:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_index=True)
```

Produces

```
  col1 col2  y0  y1
0   x1   y0   1   4
1   x2   y1   2   5
2   x2   y0   2   5
```

Getting the proper value into `col3` is the next step

### Apply

This is a bit inefficient, but it is a way to get the correct data into one column

```
df['col3'] = df[['col2', 'y0', 'y1']].apply(lambda x: x[int(x[0][1]) + 1], axis=1)
```